# Xamarin.Forms ImageSource = Device.OnPlatform obsolete

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, switch-statement, imagesource

I am using a sample from Xamarin called "TableView for a form" to test an app and came across an obsolete section, ImageSource = Device.OnPlatform which is now replaced with a switch statement. No problems here and plenty of information however, I have a peculiar problem and can not see the issue.

The code I am adding is currently commented out in below source and will compile fine this way, without the image of course. If I remove the commented section, I get an error on line 35, missing }.
If I highlight the curly brace just below the last break it is aware of its match, switch(). If I highlight the open curly brace just below that, it thinks it is part of Public SearchPage() at the top. 
Something in the switch is causing problems but I just can't see it.

I am hoping someone has run into this and may have an answer. Let me know if you need more detail.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

using Xamarin.Forms;
//using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;

namespace MiddleMeeter
{
    class SearchPage : ContentPage
    {
        public SearchPage()
        {
            Label header = new Label
            {
                Text = "TableView for a form",
                FontSize = 30,
                FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
            };

            TableView tableView = new TableView
            {
                Intent = TableIntent.Form,
                Root = new TableRoot("TableView Title")
                {
                    new TableSection("Table Section")
                    {
                        new TextCell
                        {
                            Text = "Text Cell",
                            Detail = "With Detail Text",
                        },
                        new ImageCell
                        {   
                            /**********************************************************************************************
                            switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
                            {
                                case Device.iOS:
                                ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("http://xamarin.com/images/index/ide-xamarin-studio.png"));
                                    break;
                                case Device.Android:
                                    ImageSource.FromFile("waterfront.jpg");
                                    break;
                                case Device.WinPhone:
                                    ImageSource.FromFile("Images/waterfront.jpg");
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    ImageSource.FromFile("Images/waterfront.jpg");
                                    break;
                            },
                            *///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                            Text = "Image Cell",
                            Detail = "With Detail Text",
                        },
                         new SwitchCell
                        {
                            Text = "Switch Cell"
                        },
                        new EntryCell
                        {
                            Label = "Entry Cell",
                            Placeholder = "Type text here"
                        },
                        new ViewCell
                        {
                            View = new Label
                            {
                                Text = "A View Cell can be anything you want!"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                }
            };

            // Build the page.
            this.Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Children =
                {
                    header,
                    tableView
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered: Thanks Scryptique

I wanted to post the exact code I am using to replace the sample provided by Xamarin for the Forms Gallery --> 'TableView for a form'.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

using Xamarin.Forms;
//using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;

namespace MiddleMeeter
{
    class SearchPage : ContentPage
    {
        public SearchPage()
        {
            Label header = new Label
            {
                Text = "TableView for a form",
                FontSize = 30,
                FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
            };

            TableView tableView = new TableView
            {
                Intent = TableIntent.Form,
                Root = new TableRoot("TableView Title")
                {
                    new TableSection("Table Section")
                    {
                        new TextCell
                        {
                            Text = "Text Cell",
                            Detail = "With Detail Text",
                        },
                        new ImageCell
                        {
                            // This is the call to method getSource() 
                            ImageSource = getSource(),
                            Text = "Image Cell",
                            Detail = "With Detail Text",
                        },
                         new SwitchCell
                        {
                            Text = "Switch Cell"
                        },
                        new EntryCell
                        {
                            Label = "Entry Cell",
                            Placeholder = "Type text here"
                        },
                        new ViewCell
                        {
                            View = new Label
                            {
                                Text = "A View Cell can be anything you want!"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                }
            };

            // Build the page.
            this.Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Children =
                {
                    header,
                    tableView,
                }
            };


        }

        // Method to get the format to retreive the image for Platform specific detaisl
        private ImageSource getSource()
        {
            switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
            {
                case Device.iOS:
                    return ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("https://www.xamarin.com/content/images/pages/branding/assets/xamagon.png"));
                case Device.Android:
                    return ImageSource.FromFile("Icon.png");
                case Device.WinPhone:
                    return ImageSource.FromFile("Images/waterfront.jpg");
                default:
                    return ImageSource.FromFile("Images/waterfront.jpg");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think c# supports `switch` statements in object initializers like that. Best way to resolve this would be to refactor the switch statement into a method and use it to initialize `ImageCell`.

```
ImageSource GetSource()
{
    switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
    {
        case Device.iOS:
            return ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("http://xamarin.com/images/index/ide-xamarin-studio.png"));
        case Device.Android:
            return ImageSource.FromFile("waterfront.jpg");
        case Device.WinPhone:
            return ImageSource.FromFile("Images/waterfront.jpg");
        default:
            return ImageSource.FromFile("Images/waterfront.jpg");
    }
}
```

And use it in initializer:

```
new ImageCell
{   
    ImageSource = GetSource()
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what it needed. I wish Xamarin was clear about the changes in their app, but glad this solved it.  Thanks